# How to get rid of templates folder

Tags: 12.04, directory, permanent-delete

I have a simple problem: Whenever I delete the `templates` folder in my `home` directory (`/home/[username]/` in case that info is of use) it seems to come back. It contains nothing and I have no use for it. Is there a way to make it go away permanently?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? I've just deleted my Templates directory and restarted - it's not come back.

Comment: They can come back, depending on your configuration/desktop environment. They're called "XDG user directories". I have no time to delve into it now, but you can search starting from `man xdg-user-dirs-update`

Comment: Run ` sed -i.bak 's/^XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR/#&/' ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and then remove it.....now restart and check..

Comment: I'm on 12.04, why?

Comment: Add a tag with your Ubuntu version

Comment: @A.B I did, it is the first one

Comment: Yes, it just added. https://askubuntu.com/posts/620223/revisions

Answer (score 5):

In your home folder is a configuration file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`:

```
nano ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

with a content like this:

```
[..]
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
[..]
```

You can comment out the line by which the folder will automatically create:

before:

```
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
```

after

```
#XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
```

---

Or you can use a single command in a terminal:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^\(XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR=\)/#\1/' ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

This can be undone:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^#\(XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR=\)/\1/' ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

In both cases, a backup of your file will be created:

```
~/.config/user-dirs.dirs.bak
```

Comment: I went into the .config directory and there was no user-dirs.dirs

Comment: @It'sWillem open terminal: `file .config/user-dirs.dirs ` what output you get for this?

Comment: An empty text file named user-dirs.dirs

Comment: It returned a "No such file" message

Answer (score 3):

As said by A.B., you must edit the configuration file:
`nano ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` (use nano, vim or another text editor)

After that, remove the desired directories and edit the file:
`sudo nano /etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf`.

In this file, you must set `enabled=False` to avoid the system create these directories when logging in again.

*(I found this information on https://superuser.com/questions/223918/ubuntu-permanently-remove-videos-and-public)*